# Move RefineryCMS from Local to Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hosting, refinerycms, dragonfly-gem

We decided to try using RefineryCMS for our current project and have run into some issues.
We began the project in a local development environment. The deadline is very quickly approaching. At first, we tried to move the project into production using a DreamHost server. There were issues with the images (Refinery uses Dragonfly), where our database dump wasn't brining any images over (or thumbnails).

We have exhausted our resources and still can't find a solution to our problem. I've done research, asked in the Google group, emailed people, and asked in the chat - no one has answered yet.

So, does anyone here have any idea what is the best solution for moving a project over from a local development environment to production?

I am sure I can't be the only person who has run into this issue...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In case someone arrives here with this same situation (as I did), my two cents:

I've successfully migrated between servers by dumping the database and copying `public/system`, so this is perfectly feasible and straightforward.

At first the images were not showing neither in the backend nor in the frontend, but after a couple of hours stuck I realized the problem was that I hadn't installed ImageMagick in the new server (huge facepalm).

A quick `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` solved the issue.

Of course, YMMV, but I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what version of RefineryCMS you are using, or how you configured it, but unless you chose to use Amazon S3 for uploads then your Dragonfly images and resources are being stored on the file system. So in addition to that database dump, you'll probably want to look in the `public/system/` folder and copy everything in the `images` and `resources` folders up to the server too.

Comment: We are using the latest stable version of Refinery (1.0.3). We tried to make sure we copied all images and resources, but still had an issue with admin thumbnails. However, since you mentioned it, I will double check. Updates will be posted.

Comment: Thumbnails in Dragonfly are generated and should not need to be copied, so maybe the problem is related to that.