# Are Strange Strings in URLs normal for Refinery?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, url, imagemagick, refinerycms

So I have this site I'm moving from inhouse servers due to the age of the servers. While in the process of moving the site, I noticed that the images have strange strings in the URLs, such as

```
<img src="/system/images/BAhbBlsHOgZmIiwyMDExLzExLzIyLzEyXzIyXzI3XzkwOV9OZXdzX2Jhbm5lci5qcGc/News-banner.jpg" title="News Banner" alt="News Banner" rel="225x255" width="909" height="303">

<img class="image-align-left" src="/system/images/BAhbB1sHOgZmIjUyMDExLzEyLzIxLzA5XzMzXzQ1XzUzM19XaWxsb3VnaGJ5U3VwcGx5TG9nby5wbmdbCDoGcDoKdGh1bWIiDTExMHgxMTA+/WilloughbySupplyLogo.png" width="83" height="89">
```

I checked the filestructure, both on the old servers and on the new servers, and those paths do NOT show up anywhere.

It's causing problems where I moving the sites to, shown in the fact that the images don't show up at all. At first, I thought [installing ImageMagick would fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6987976/move-refinerycms-from-local-to-production), and for one of the three sites, it did, but the other two sites still have VERY broken images.

Can someone explain why the images have such weird strings in the URLs, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Might be a cachebuster of some sort. If it were PHP I'd check the .htaccess rules.

Comment: I don't think it's a cache buster because the url stays the same even after refreshing the page.

Comment: That's often the case with a cachebuster. The ones my company uses only change the URL if the image contents change.

Comment: ahh. sorry, I had a misunderstanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These URLs are from Dragonfly which is the Image processing library that Refinery uses.

What this URL does is encode job instructions for how to process the image that you are requesting. These instructions can be many things such as resize, crop, watermark, distort in some way.  This means that you can request the same image with different instructions and it will appear differently each time.

For more information the [Dragonfly URL documentation is a good read](http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.URLs.html)

Comment: Awesome link! After playing around with it for a month, I suspected as much, but now I know as much! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I get the same thing with my refinery sites.  It appears Refinery (or imagemagick, or one of the other gems it depends on) generates temporary URLs for assets/resources.  This is usually a good thing as it helps prevent leeching and hotlinking, among other things :)

Comment: If Refinery is generating a URL for each image, wouldn't the path be right? Part of my problem is that the images don't show up.

Comment: The path is probably a fake path, just like there's no actual HTML page at `questions/10557865/are-strange-strings-in-urls-normal-for-refinery` on StackOverflow.

Comment: Could be imagemagick screwing up.  That thing is temperamental.  I'd also double check server settings and permissions on the image files.

Comment: I would say that either the ImageMagick configuration is incorrect or you're hosting on something like Heroku and not using S3.  Another cause is that ImageMagick may not be at a compatible version for the version of Dragonfly you're using on the sites that aren't fixed.